# JavaScript Manipulation with WebKit - unable to pass unload message to WebKit

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

This is my first time dabbling in WebKit and JavaScript together. I'm really interested in the manipulation of Swift code with JavaScript and vise verse. My question pertains to the response message from JavaScript and printing that message in Xcode while debugging. Listed below is what I currently have. Everything works, however, I can't seem to get the message from the JavaScript to print once the window loads in the application. My info.plist is setup to handle localhost urls, so I'm thinking that the code I'm using is depreciated? I originally referenced this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405) to get the code that I'm working on below.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

        userContentController.add(self, name: "test")

        config.userContentController = userContentController
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(webView)
        let layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        if let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/WebKitExample/") {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

}

extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
      if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
          print(messageBody)
      }
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebKitExample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <script>
              function printHelloWorld() {
                  window.webkit.messageHandlers.test.postMessage("Hello, world!");
              }
              window.onload = printHelloWorld;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on where to look to get this working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved same kind of issue like this

```
let script = WKUserScript(source: "window.print = function() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.print.postMessage('print') }", injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "print")
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: link)!))
```

This is how I captured the message

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
if message.name == "print" {
        //manage your action here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed. I will check that this evening and get back to you. Letting you know if that works or not. Thanks again!